# Plot bone mineral density (BMD) curves with t score (2.5 SD) interval?

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

Sorry if this is not well asked, first ever question.

Aim: to calculate the bone mineral density T-score (+/- 2.5 SD for sex and age specific BMD value). To say whether a patient is osteoporotic or not.

I am trying to do this graphically using ggplot 2 and geom_smooth

I am using the NHANES dataset (https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2013-2014/DXXFEM_H.htm#DXXINBMD) which is accessed through nhanesA package.

**r load programs:**

```
library(nhanesA)
library(ggplot2)
```

I am interested only in the intertrochanteric BMD, age and sex.

**r load data:**

```
nhanesTableVars('EXAM', "DXXFEM_D")
DXXFEM_D  <- nhanes('DXXFEM_D')
fem_d <- DXXFEM_D
demo_d <- nhanes('DEMO_D')
demo_d <- nhanesTranslate('DEMO_D', 'RIAGENDR', data=demo_d)
DXXFEM_D_vars  <- nhanesTableVars('EXAM', 'DXXFEM_D', namesonly=TRUE)
DXXFEM_D <- nhanesTranslate('DXXFEM_D', DXXFEM_D_vars, data=DXXFEM_D)
FEM_demo <- merge(demo_d, DXXFEM_D)
FEM_demo_1 <- FEM_demo[,c(5,6,55)]
```

Then I attempted the plot but with a levels argument in the "geom_smooth" does not work with level at 2.5.

**r plot BMD with SD:**

```
ggplot(data = FEM_demo_1, aes(x = RIDAGEYR, y = DXXINBMD, group = RIAGENDR, color = RIAGENDR)) + 
  geom_smooth(se = TRUE, level = 2.5) + 
  scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0,85,1), breaks = seq(0,85,5))
```

1) I would ideally like a plot which shows the mean, -1SD (which refers to Osteopaenia) and -2SD which refers to cut off for osteoporosis which can be used to translate BMD into clinical criteria. Is there a way to do this?

2) Is there anyway to do this numerically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for plot with mean, -1SD and -2SD. You can add styling to your liking. The calculations for mean and SD are done beforehand in dataframe.

```
data <- aggregate(FEM_demo_1$DXXINBMD, by=list(FEM_demo_1$RIAGENDR, FEM_demo_1$RIDAGEYR), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
names(data) <- c("gender", "age", "mean")
data[,"sd"] <- aggregate(FEM_demo_1$DXXINBMD, by=list(FEM_demo_1$RIAGENDR, FEM_demo_1$RIDAGEYR), FUN=sd, na.rm=TRUE)[3]

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=age, group=gender))+
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(y=mean))+
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(y=mean-sd))+
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(y=mean-(2*sd)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this numerically? So, input age and gender to get a mean line value and -2sd value? Thanks again

Comment: See the "data" dataframe in my answer. It has the mean and sd values by group and you can index it easily. Or write a function which prints the values you require.

Comment: Thanks very much! you are a great help